# What is the name of the long cable/plug attachment on the MacBook MagSafe charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, power, magsafe

My MacBook 2015's MagSafe charger has two attachments for plugging it into the wall:

1. a simple plug, which slides/snaps onto the charging block
2. a loooong cable, one end of which can slide into the charging block and the other end has a plug on it for going into the wall

I would like to know the name of the second attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable in question (pun intended) is called **[Power Adapter Extension Cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK122LL/A/power-adapter-extension-cable?fnode=8b)**.

> ## Overview
>
> The 1.8-meter Power Adapter Extension Cable is an AC extension cord that provides extra length for your Apple power adapter. Use it with MagSafe and MagSafe 2 power adapters, 10W and 12W USB-A power adapters, and 29W, 30W, 61W, and 96W USB-C power adapters.
>
> [image]

<sub>**P.S.**: The attached image is for illustration purpose and is obtained from the aforementioned hyperlink from the Apple Online Store.</sub>